# Coordinate ring of zero locus of unit circle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> How to characterize the coordinate ring of $Z(x^{2}+y^{2}-1)$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field with $\operatorname{char}k\neq 2$.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm trying to find out if we can prove or disprove that the coordinate ring is isomorphic to $k[t,t^{-1}]$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the second part of your question, it is true that $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $k[t,t^{-1}]$. For instance, let $i$ be one of the square roots of $-1$ in the algebraically closed field $k$, and send $t$ to $y-ix$, $t^{-1}$ to $y+ix$. The inverse isomorphism sends $x$ to $i(t-t^{-1})/2$ and $y$ to $(t+t^{-1})/2$.

Comment: This approach is certainly correct if the characteristic of the field is unequal to 2. But if the characteristic of the field is 2, would it still be true that $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $k[t,t^{-1}]?$

Comment: Sorry I saw your question only now, 21 months later, @Johnduck . But in characteristic two, $x^2+y^2-1=(x+y+1)^2$, a line  counted twice.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the coordinate ring is $k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$.

Comment: Maybe we should be a little more careful. We have some algebraic set $Y$ and we want to find $k[x, y]/I(Y)$, where $I(Y)$ is the ideal of $Y$. Certainly $(x^2 + y^2 - 1) \subset I(Y)$, but equality here doesn't seem to be a matter of definition. [And maybe the OP should specify what $k$ is.]

Comment: I am sorry. You are right.