# Is the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ or the ring $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ unique factorization domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> I wonder if either the coordinate ring $A(X):=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ or the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ are unique factorization domains?

I know that those are isomorphic, so the answere for one of those would do it. In my trys of solving this issue, I saw that:
$y^2 = (1-x)(1+x)$ ist a none-unique factorization in irreducible elements, because $y, (1-x)$ and $(1+x)$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$. But I can't even prove, that $y$ is irreducible. I know, that there are no none-units nor units, which I could multiply and get $y$ again. As far as I know, the units in $A(X)$ are the constant polynomials.

I hope that someone can understand my issue (so in advance in hope you can read my spelling w/o getting hurt :) ..) and make this topic clear to me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]$? I'm pretty sure the first one is not local.

Comment: The second one is also not local. It's just a localisation.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back — the usual projection to a line should work. But this was not obvious at first glance.

Comment: @Hoot, yes I do agree on that part.

Comment: I just saw that on that post:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112033/coordinate-ring-of-zero-locus-of-unit-circle
and still on a proof.

Comment: @JakobHansen Geometrically, these two rings are isomorphic because over $\mathbb{C}$, a circle and hyperbola are isomorphic as curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Note that $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] \cong \mathbb{C}[t,u]/(tu - 1)$.  Letting $t = x+iy$ and $u = x - iy$ we have $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = (x+iy)(x-iy) - 1 = tu - 1$, hence this map transforms the circle into a hyperbola.

Comment: The localization of a UFD is a UFD : see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140584.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]=\mathbb{C}[t]_t$. Now, as localization of a UFD is a UFD, we are done.

In fact, we actually have a stronger result. Localization of a PID is again a PID . Since $\mathbb{C}[t]$ is a PID, $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is a PID as well.

Comment: Well, I didn't know, that $\mathbb C[t,t^{-1}]=\mathbb{C}[t]_t$ is the localizsation fo $\mathbb C[t]$ at the Element t. The last statement is known by the way.

I wonder, because of http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/ag06/ag03.pdf example 3.

Comment: It's wrong. $Y$ is not irreducible. As for why $K[C] \not\simeq K[X]$, observe that the only invertible elements of $K[X]$ are the constant polynomials, hence the image of $t$ has to be a constant polynomial. But then that gives rise to a contradiction.

Comment: So what's the factorization of X or Y, if it's not irreducible? I see, that $y^2=1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$, so I know that $y$ must devide $(1-x)$ or $(1+x)$. So there is an Element $a\in A(X)$ with $y=a(1+x)$ or $y=a(1-x)$. But a should not be a unit. Units are the constants, so $a$ shouldn't be a unit. Right?

Comment: $y$ may not divide $1-x$ or $1+x$, since $y$ is not prime in this ring. As far as irreducibility of $y$ is concerned, note that $(x+iy-1)(x-iy+1)=2iy$.

Comment: Well nice, that's it. Thank you.

Comment: @Shalec, glad to help :)

Comment: Perhaps the author meant to work over $\mathbb R$. There's probably something interesting about factoriality to say in that case.

Comment: @Hoot: you're right $\mathbf R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ is not factorial. In fact its class group is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/2$, a generator being the ideal of a real point like $(x-1,y)$. This ideal cannot be cut out by only one real polynomial.

Comment: The author noted in the beginning, that the field are algebraically closed. Well I still got my probs with showing that:$\phi:\ A(X)\to \mathbb C[t,t^{-1}], t\mapsto (x+iy), t^{-1}\mapsto (x-iy)$ is isomorphic. The proof for injectivity is left.

Comment: The proof was done by defining the inverse homomorphism, which maps $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(t-t^{-1})$ and $y \mapsto \frac{i}{2}(t+t^{-1})$. Well I'm actually not sure about the sign. If someone needs to show the bijectivity, just define this map for inverting x+iy and x-iy, so that $\psi(x+iy)=t$ and $\psi(x-iy)=t^{-1}$.